# Multiple li tags

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to display multiple li tags of HTML in a single line as shown below. Basically we need to display the first few li elements in a single line and rest in a list as shown below link.  Thanks.

[image: Looking similar display]

Answer (score 0):

See CSS and positionning possibilities. You've to change regular comportements of li in layout (default one)by setting new rules. i.e.: using float CSS properties but they're many mny ways to set and place elements in the way you like in your page.
When using bootstrap you can even use grid predefine layout fitting what you want(so for example fill each grid cell with one li) but that seems more complex and make you write more i think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

I created an example [pen](https://codepen.io/dulara-malindu/pen/YbNpMO) for you.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Item1</span>
      <span>Item2</span>
      <span>Item3</span>
    <div>
  </li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-grow:1;
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Place your image files instead of the `span` tags. **Make sure you add** `display:inline-block;` property to them and give proper widths and heights to the image files.

The magic behind this is [flexbox](https://flaviocopes.com/flexbox/)